# How to insert a personalised centred horizontal line separation in a thesis title page

Tags: titles, koma-script, covers

I am trying to insert a horizontal line to separate the title of my thesis and the subtitle that simply describes that it is a PhD Tesis. However I have played around with `\hrule` and `\hfill` commands with little pleasantly aesthetical results.

How I would like the line to be is as follows:

- For the line to not be immediately attached to the title (as in the MWE) but rather be a customisable short distance away.
- To be a customisable distance above from the `\subtitle`.
- For the line to not span the text space width and to be centred, and its distance to be customisable, but lets say 1/3 of the text space width.

Potentially I would like the possibility for it to be a fancy line such as a double line with the top one bold and the lower one less so, but that is currently of lesser importance.

Please find below my MWE, thank you.

```
\documentclass[
DIV=11,
%fontsize=12,
twoside,
headinclude=false,
titlepage=firstiscover,
abstract=true,
headsepline=true,
footsepline=true,
chapterprefix=true, %this allows for editing of the chapter titles
headings=big,
bibliography=totoc,%adds unnumbered Bibliography chapter to toc
captions=tableheading
]{scrreprt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PREAMBLE
%%%%%%%%%%% Packages
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace} %using this package allows one to not need to know the stretch value associated with the DIV factor chosen to achieve the chosen linespread. It has to be noted that for a title page the line spacing should be reset and that this spacing is NOT applied to footnotes and floats of table and figure captions.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minitoc} 
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage[hidelinks
,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=4 %This is for the appendix command formulated
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wasysym}


\linespread{1.5} %imperial uses 1.5 
\flushbottom

%%%%%%%%%%% STYLING
\makeatletter

\def\phdtitle#1{\gdef\@phdtitle{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TITLE PAGE
\def\titlepagehere{
    \titlehead{
        \Large \centering  \phantom a
        An Awesome College of Science \& Technology
    }
    \subject{Department of Happiness \\
       %\includegraphics[width=4cm]{}
    }
    \title{\@phdtitle \\
    \hrule %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Line here...
    }

    \subtitle{\hrule %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ...or line here?
    \\ PhD Thesis}

    \author{Best Author}
    \date{
        \vskip 1cm
        \normalsize Submitted \\
        \Large October 2014 \\
        \vskip 1cm
        \normalsize Supervisors: \\
        \Large Super. Man \\
        Cool. Dude \\
        \vskip 1cm
        \large Submitted in part fulfilment of the requirements for the degree of
        Doctor of Philosophy in Life Long Happiness College
    %\publishers{}
        }
    \makeatother}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TITLE PAGE
%%%%%%% WRITE TITLE HERE
\phdtitle{Super Long and Complicated Title for an Awesome Thesis that is at least 2 lines long}

\titlepagehere
\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CHAPTERS
%\body

\chapter{Test}

Test

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the following code produce what you want?

Btw, since you use `setspace`, you should use the `onelinespacing` command instead of `\linespread`: it take care of the footnotes linespacing and a few other spacing parameters.

```
\documentclass[
DIV=11,
%fontsize=12,
twoside,
headinclude=false,
titlepage=firstiscover,
abstract=true,
headsepline=true,
footsepline=true,
chapterprefix=true, %this allows for editing of the chapter titles
headings=big,
bibliography=totoc,%adds unnumbered Bibliography chapter to toc
captions=tableheading
]{scrreprt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PREAMBLE
%%%%%%%%%%% Packages
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace} %using this package allows one to not need to know the stretch value associated with the DIV factor chosen to achieve the chosen linespread. It has to be noted that for a title page the line spacing should be reset and that this spacing is NOT applied to footnotes and floats of table and figure captions.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{minitoc}
%\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage[hidelinks
,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=4 %This is for the appendix command formulated
]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\linespread{1.5} %imperial uses 1.5
\flushbottom

%%%%%%%%%%% STYLING
\makeatletter

\def\phdtitle#1{\gdef\@phdtitle{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TITLE PAGE
\def\titlepagehere{
    \titlehead{
        \Large \centering  \phantom a
        An Awesome College of Science \& Technology
    }
    \subject{Department of Happiness \\
       %\includegraphics[width=4cm]{}
    }
    \title{\@phdtitle\\[-1.5ex]%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Line here...
    \rule{0.33\linewidth}{2.4pt}\\[-3.7ex] \rule{0.33\linewidth}{0.6pt}
    \vskip -1ex
    }
    \subtitle{
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ...or line here?
        PhD Thesis}
%
    \author{Best Author}
    \date{
        \vskip 1cm
        \normalsize Submitted \\
        \Large October 2014 \\
        \vskip 1cm
        \normalsize Supervisors: \\
        \Large Super. Man \\
        Cool. Dude \\
        \vskip 1cm
        \large Submitted in part fulfilment of the requirements for the degree of
        Doctor of Philosophy in Life Long Happiness College
    %\publishers{}
        }
    \makeatother}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TITLE PAGE
%%%%%%% WRITE TITLE HERE
\phdtitle{Super Long and Complicated Title for an Awesome Thesis that is at least 2 lines long}

\titlepagehere
\maketitle
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CHAPTERS
%\body
%
%\chapter{Test}
%
%Test
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah this is getting there yes! It's much better like this, I am unfamiliar with the `[-1.5ex]` command you used to add space after the `@phdtitle`. Also could you expand a little on how to use the `onelinespacing` command to get 1 and 1.5 linespread please?

Comment: `[-1.5ex]` is an optional argument to `\\` (one baseline skip minus 1.5ex — ex is the height of the letter`x` in the current font, so that if change fontsize, say, it will also change). When there is no explicit line break, e.g. after the short rules, I use  `\vskip 1ex`. Naturally, these value are experimental and certainly you *should* experiment.

Comment: Thank you, I am experimenting and even adding colour as we speak. How would you recommend achieving 1.5 and 1 linespreads with the `onelinespacing` command, I am not too familiar with what `setspace` means, I will read about it, but I'm curious about the difference bwtween using `\inespread` vs `onelinespacing` command

Comment: As for the use of `setspace`, documentation is in the code `setspace.sty`. Roughly, `onelinespacing`, `\singlelinespacing`, `\doublespacing` are switches that is equivalent to `\linestretch{…}`. The values depend on the font size, and onehalf spacing  is *not* 1.5. Moreover they take care of some other parameters like, not only footnotes line spacing already mentioned,  vertical spacing of displayed equations and a few others. It's not as simple as it might seem at first glance!

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. It rarely is as simple as one might think when using LaTeX but that is also its advantage.

Comment: `setspace` is the name of the `package`, that has a general command: `\setstretch{…}`. You can try `setstretch{1.5}`. But I suspect the real requirement is the equivalent of onelinespacing (for your information, for a 10 pt document, it is set to 1.25). Perhaps you should ask. Take a look at `l2tabu`, §1.4: it's a guide about more or less deadful sins in LaTeX.